# <script> document.location.href='';</script> & Go to page related questions

Tags: php, sms, location

```
<? echo "<script> document.location.href='main.php';</script>"; ?>
```

This code is running well

But, sending values ​​from the form page

```
<form action="smssend.php" method="post" id="quickform"> 
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="<? =PHP_SELF?>">
```

This gives a value to the next page

```
<? echo "<script> document.location.href='$_POST[returnUrl]';</script>"; ?>
```

Run time error occurs if the source and the page will not move.

Does what I'm wrong?

Under the form page I received the message from the phone number with reference to the page source to handle less.

```
<?php

$config['SMS_ID']="test";
$config['SMS_PW']="test1234";
$config['cf_tel']='01234567';

$post_data = array(
            "remote_id"       => $config['SMS_ID'],
            "remote_pass"     => $config['SMS_PW'], 
            "remote_num"      => 1, 
            "remote_reserve"  => 0, 
            "remote_phone"    => $_POST[number],
            "remote_callback" => $config['cf_tel'],
            "remote_msg"      => $_POST[counsle]
        );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mymunja.co.kr/Remote/RemoteSms.html" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$msg = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
<? echo "<script> alert('Done');</script>"; ?>
<? echo "<script> document.location.href='$_POST[returnUrl]';</script>"; ?>
```

Comment: try var_dumping `var_dump($_POST["returnUrl"]);` and posting the output .. please post the errors you are getting so we can get a clear picture of what is going wrong

Comment: Please share more details. Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem? Why is this question tagged with SMS?

Answer (score 3):

```
<? echo "<script> document.location.href="$_POST[returnUrl]";</script>"; ?>
```

your problem is with string delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Try use `<html></html>` tag.

```
<? echo "<html><script> alert('Done');</script></html>"; ?>


<? echo "<html><script> document.location.href='$_POST[returnUrl]';</script></html>"; ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn fromit

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="<? =PHP_SELF?>">
```

should actually be

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="<?=PHP_SELF?>">
```

View source of your form and make sure the value of your hidden input has the correct value.